# date/time - date conversion problem

Tags: datetime, date

I'm passing a date/time field as a parameter to a page like this:

```
&startDate={!object.Start_date__c}
```

Start_date__c in object is a Date/Time field.

But when I open the link I get this error:

```
System.TypeException: Invalid date/time
```

In the page I'm linking with that parameter, which I can not modify for now, I can see that this is the line that generates the error:

```
DateTime startDate  =   DateTime.valueOf(startDateInputString);
```

How can I modify the parameter in input to make this work?

The problem seems to be that I'm passing 01-24-2013 1.00 with a blank space in my url.
Thanks

Comment: maybe related to the date getting url encoded.  Try `DateTime.valueOf(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(startDateInputString))`

Answer (score 4):

Here's what a DateTime looks like when blatted out on a page as a string:

**(format one)**

```
Fri Nov 30 21:55:38 GMT 2012
```

You can't just hydrate that string back into a DateTime. You must [construct](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Datetime_static_methods.htm) or [deserialize](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Json_deserialize.htm) it.

Here's what a serialized DateTime looks like:

**(format two)**

```
"2014-01-24T16:56:27.044Z"
```

*It's not the same as the above string output.* You need something more like this:

```
public DateTime dateFromUrl() {
    String serializedDate = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startDate');
    return (DateTime)Json.deserialize(serializedDate, DateTime.class);
}
```

And as a good web citizen, if you're serving up the parameter in a link it should be URL encoded:

```
https://c.na1.visual.force.com/apex/MyPage?startDate=2014-01-24T16%3A56%3A27.044Z
```

And you might note that the `DateTime.valueOf` method expects yet a different value:

**(format three)**

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Knowing these, we can ensure that we are creating (and expecting) matching date formats.

Answer (score 2):

I would try encoding the datetime to get a properly encoded url param, then decoding in your controller...

Before adding to the url...

```
&startDate={!URLENCODE(object.Start_date__c)}
```

In your controller on the receiving end...

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.valueOf(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(startDateInputString));
```

Comment: Thanks! {!URLENCODE(object.Start_date__c)} doesnt work and gives error Incorrect argument type for function 'URLENCODE(), seems it accepts string only and datetime/date when provided throws error.

Comment: Also the urlDecode needs 2nd parameter too of Encoding Type for eg startOfWeek = Date.valueOf(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(startOfWeekParam,'UTF-8'));

Answer (score 0):

Set this in the URL:

```
?startDate={!URLENCODE(TEXT(object.Start_date__c))}
```

and in the controller try this code:

```
Date startDate =  Date.valueOf( EncodingUtil.urlDecode( ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('startDate'), 'UTF-8') );
```